# Error while creating azure sql datawarehouse database

Tags: azure

I am facing some problems while creating Azure `SQL Datawarehouse` database.
I am using following query in the `Azure SQL Datawarehouse` query pane:

```
CREATE DATABASE TESTDWHDB COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (EDITION='datawarehouse', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'DW100', MAXSIZE= 1024 GB);
```

Error Message:-

> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Parse error at line: 1, column:
>   17: Incorrect syntax near 'TESTDWHDB'.

Could anybody help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: any update for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your query code in Azure sql **Query editor**, it works fine to create **TESTDWHDB** Datawarehouse. And I check your query syntax with this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-azure-sql-data-warehouse?view=azure-sqldw-latest), it seems that there is no difference. Fore more details about Datawarehouse, you could read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/create-data-warehouse-portal).

In Azure sql Query editor:

[image]

In Azure Sql Server:

[image]

In Datawarehouse:

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful, you could vote it up or mark it as answer to help other community members to find. Thanks.